# Using setTimeOut in a worker thread?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, web-worker

I'm trying to use a library that is realized by relying a lot on `window.setTimeOut`. I want to use it in a worker thread that doesn't have access to the `window`scope.

Is it possible to use a polyfill or use any other method that does the same thing within this context?

Comment: Can you please post some code, the library you are using and what you have tried?

Comment: Can't you use `setTimeout` on the global scope (without using `window.`)? [This](https://gist.github.com/BinaryMuse/19aa812cd2277d8c9555) looks like a good workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` (**not** <del>`setTimeOut`</del>) perfectly well. Just use it as global variable:

```
setTimeout( ... stuff stuff stuff ..., number);
```

And if you want to use global scope object for some reason, `self` is defined both in Browser and Web Worker:

```
self.setTimeout( ... stuff stuff stuff ..., number);
```

If a library is trying to access `window`, just define it to be global scope:

```
self.window = self;
window.setTimeout( ... stuff stuff stuff ..., number);
```

If you have further doubts, please check this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ryovLea1/1/